# Question regarding inequality sign changes and negative divisors

Tags: inequality

I just have a simple question. Why does an inequality sign change when divided by a negative number? E.g: $-x > 3$ results to $x <-3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Negating both sides of an inequality is equivalent to swapping the two sides over.

For instance,

$$ a<b $$

becomes

$$ a-b < 0 $$

and then

$$ -b < -a $$

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as taking all the stuff on the left hand side to the right and taking all the stuff from the right to the left hand side.

Answer (score 0):

The notion of "flipping" is a shortcut of sorts that comes about from addition properties of inequalities. If you know $x< -3$ is a true inequality, and you know that the inequality holds if you add the same quantity to both sides, then $$x+(3-x)<-3+(3-x) \\ \implies (x-x)+3<(3-3)-x \\ \implies 3<-x$$